# SQL Compare stock table, Average Price + 10% Round up & Update Field

Tags: sql, sql-update, compare, average

I have a SQL table called `tblStock`. It holds the details of thousands of items of stocks sold by my company. It has the following columns:

```
StockID
Make
Model
YearManufacture
Price
GuidePrice
```

For unsold items in this table I want to add the predicted sales value into the field called `GuidePrice`, based on the figures for stock already sold,
e.g if I have the below item:

```
StockID: 123456
Make: VW
Model: Beetle
YearManufacture: 1975
Price: 2000.00
GuidePrice:
```

I want to calculate a guide price based on the prices I’ve got for all the previous 1975 VW Beetles I’ve sold.

I want to take the mean average price for all the previous 1975 VW Beetles in `tblStock` and add 10%, then round up to the nearest 500.00 and insert in the `GuidePrice` column.

The overall calculation is more complicated than this, but this is the part I’m stuck on. I’d appreciate if anyone could give me some tips!

EDIT:
This works to get the average, but I'm having to type in each Make, Model & Year
(And ROUND up after)

```
Update tblStock
set GuidePrice=(Select  AVG(Price) 
from tblStock 
INNER JOIN
tblMake ON tblStock.Car_idMake = tblMake.idMake INNER JOIN
tblModel ON tblStock.Car_idModel = tblModel.idModel
where MakeD='Cat'
AND ModelD ='320CL'
AND YearManufacture='2004')

where idStock='140038410'
```

While this doesn't work at all;

```
update tblStock t1
set GuidePrice = (select 1.10 * AVG(Price)
from tblStock t2
where t2.Car_idMake = t1.Car_idMake
                and t2.Car_idModel = t1.Car_idModel
                and t2.YearManufacture = t1.YearManufacture )
```

where idStock='140038410'

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Could you make a small example to illustrate your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this to update that specific car:

```
update tblStock t1
set GuidePrice = (select 1.10 * avg(Price)
                  from tblStock t2
                  where t2.Make = t1.make
                    and t2.Model = t1.Model
                    and t2.YearManufacture = t1.YearManufacture)
where StockID = 123456
```

Round up to the nearest 500.00 still missing.

How do you know if a car is sold or unsold? is `Price` null if unsold?

If that's the case, and you want to update `GuidePrice` for all unsold cars, replace the `WHERE` clause above with:

```
WHERE GuidePrice IS NULL
```

Comment: This looks right but isn't working. I've used
`update tblStock t1
set GuidePrice = (select 1.10 * avg(Price)
                  from tblStock t2
                  where t2.Car_idMake = t1.Car_idMake
                    and t2.Car_idModel = t1.Car_idModel
                    and t2.YearManufacture = t1.YearManufacture)
where idStock='140039256' `

I'm getting;

**Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 't1'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
**

Comment: Either your dbms doesn't support this, or you need an AS before t1/t2.